# How does one unite Bindu, Prakriti and Kundalini?

Tags: prakruti, kundalini

The Bindu is there as One, Prakriti is there as Mother and Kunalini is there as as power. How does one unite these three and what is the result when this is realized ?

Comment: This bindu…should be a point of convergence…a point where…yoga…tantra…scriptural knowledge etc….”converge”…a realm of the “subjective”….which “only” the yogis understand.Have little clue about the answer…except that…the yogi will be very close to…getting rid of all samskaras(when this union is about to take place).

Comment: We can find a lot of "theoretical".. details...online....given by the esteemed swami Sivananda(who was a great yogi also).

Comment: Kundalini should be united with Parashiva. Regarding Bindu are u talking about Nada-Bindu? @FrankHestermann

Comment: @Rickross I am talking about the red Siddhi center in the middle of the forehead. I am not sure if Kundalini rises above this center to Paramashiva.